# Acrobat - Form - "Submit" to Email Not Working

Tags: adobe-acrobat, forms

I created a PDF Form with a "submit" button that is suppose to email the completed PDF form via the "default client".  This doesn't seem to work and I keep getting the following error,

"An error occurred while trying to create a mail document.  Adobe Acrobat DC is unable to complete your request. If you are not sure how to proceed further, you can save your form and return it manually using your Internet email service."

Anyone know how to correct this issue?

I am currently using Outlook (v. 15.24) on a Mac as my default email client and the most current MacOS.

Comment: Have you tried the same PDF on another machine? That'll at least show you wether the issue is with the PDF or with your system (either Acrobat or your mail)

Comment: Yes.  i tried it on another machine. The default email client on that machine was "Airmail" and it worked perfectly. I hit "submit" and it opened up a new message with the attachment and simply had to hit send. I believe "Outlook" is the issue but not sure why.

Answer (score -1):

A PDF or a webpage form does not know what to do with the information if it is not declared.

Normally a submit button needs to have an instruction on it pointing to a web service.

An analogy. You write a letter and put it on an envelope.

This letter will not go anywhere no matter how many stamps you "submit" on it. You need to write a proper addres and insert it on a mailbox, where specialized people will deliver the letter using the necessary resources.

That is what a web service do, needs to have an infraestructure to send your data to a specific location.

Comment: When you create a submit button within Acrobat, you can assign it numerous actions. One being to open up the "default mail client" and then open a new message and attach the "PDF" as an attachment. The action is as follows <mailto:[your email address]> The action works with some clients but not with others. Outlook being a finicky one. So to your answer, the "submit" button does have a declaration in the form of an "action".  Unless I'm misunderstanding.